# Дано длинное целое неотрицательное число. Заменить в его шестнадцетиричном представлении все нечётные цифры на нули

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Ранее здесь был вопрос с приложенным кодом, я его заменил на ответ, увы,удалить вопрос не могу.
Данный код всё делает верно,но он выполняет все действия с 16-разрядными цифрами,без перевода. Ответ дан.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
    unsigned n, m, mask1;
    int i, j, l;
    cout << "Vvedite chislo n" << endl;
    cin >> hex >> n;
    cout << "Ishodnoe chislo = " << hex << n << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(n) * 2; i++)
    {
        m = n << (32 - (1 + 4 * i));
        if (m >> (32 - 1) == 1)
        {
            mask1 = n << (32 - 4 * (i + 1));
            mask1 = mask1 >> 28;
            mask1 = mask1 << 32 - 4 * (8 - i);
            n = n ^ mask1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Preobrazovannoe chislo = " << hex << n << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Для начала: как будет компилироваться без   <iomanip>?...

Comment: Это единственная ошибка,которую вы видете?

Comment: я же написал ясно: для начала... А вообше

Comment: Сам код является лишней писаниной, и, по мне, даже  не стоит пытаться в  нем разобраться. Есть пропущенные скобки в операторе mask1 = mask1 << 32 - 4 * (8 - i); есть лишный обьект j и  стоило бы обьявлять  i   как  unsigned ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да просто любой алгоритм с циклом для такой простой задачи уже нонсенс...

Comment: @Harry, ну я о том же...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну зачем вся эта возня? :)

```
unsigned long magic(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned long mask = ~(x & 0x11111111);
    mask &= (mask << 1) | 1;
    mask &= (mask << 2) | 3;
    return x&mask;
}
```

Ну или, [соответственно](https://ideone.com/NC8sfo),

```
unsigned long long magic(unsigned long long x)
{
    unsigned long long mask = ~(x & 0x1111111111111111);
    mask &= (mask << 1) | 1;
    mask &= (mask << 2) | 3;
    return x&mask;
}
```

Смотрю на навороченные циклы... Люди, что, эффективность больше никого не интересует в принципе? :(

Для особо непонятливых.

```
unsigned long x;
cin >> x;
cout << "Decimal: " << x << endl;
cout << "Hex:     " << hex << setfill('0') << setw(8) << x << endl;
cout << "After processing:\n";
x = magic(x);
cout << "Decimal: " << x << endl;
cout << "Hex:     " << hex << setfill('0') << setw(8) << x << endl;
```

и вводите руками, что хотите...

Comment: эффектиность всегда интересует, но еще нужно уметь придумать решение получше, а лучшее решение есть почти всегда

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да просто что-то у меня сегодня день вообще не очень... а тут такая простая задача - и начали такое чудить :( Я еще понимаю, если б десятеричная система - но ведь 16-ричная - просто побитово укладывается! Ну, вот слишком эмоционально и отреагировал. День, правда, все равно легче не стал :)

Comment: у вас день, а у меня несколько месяцев как не очень, и времени достаточно не бывает, чтобы концентрироваться на  чем то (работа, семья, внуки,  события разного рода...).   Что касается ваших комментарий, не нахожу в них ничего некорректного  и  излишне эмоционального. Все нормально (по моему так....)

Comment: Спасибо большое,решение подходящее,но как я понял,мы изначально вводим число 16-разрядное,да и вводим мы внутри программы. А надо вводить десятеричное,а выводить шестнадцатеричное,заменив нечётные эл-ты нулями(ну это,как я понял и проверил,выполняется)

Comment: @СOM Вы что, издеваетесь?... Вводите что хотите и как хотите - **в компьютере нет шестнадцатеричных или десятичных чисел**! То, как вы вводите или выводите - **никак не связано с представлением чисел в компьютере**. Разжевал в ответе, пользуйтесь...

Comment: Прошу прощение,просто незнание некоторых моментов(студент),понял,принял

Comment: `x & ~((((uint64_t)-1 / 15) & x) * 15)`. Мои любимые масочки. :)

Answer (score 6):

Проверяем, что i-й ниббл (полубайт) нечётный -  т.е. в нём установлен младший разряд

```
    n and (1 << 4 * i)
```

Если да, то делаем маску типа `FFF0FFF`

```
    ~(0xF << 4 * i)
```

и накладываем её на число.

Comment: очень рационально

Comment: @ARHovsepyan С циклом - рационально? Для 64-разрядного - 16 оборотов цикла?! Маску нужно делать в одно обращение... Гляньте на мой вариант.

Comment: @Harry,  я тоже  подумал о таком решении, но уверен, что вы предложите получше...

Answer (score 1):

Как-то сложно у вас, я бы написал так. Для начала берем код для перевода DEC => HEX, он очень прост:

```
// C#
int n = 11111;
while (n > 0)
{
    int d = n % 16
    Console.WriteLine("0123456789ABCDEF"[d]); // <== Здесь выводится очередная
    //  шестнадцатеричная цифра, проверьте ее с помощью калькулятора
    n /= 16;
}
```

Теперь добавляем код для одновременного сбора числа назад:

```
int n = 11111, r = 0, e = 1;
while (n > 0)
{
    int d = n % 16
    r += d * e;
    e *= 16;
    n /= 16;
}
Console.WriteLine(r); // <== Тут проверяем что получилось то же, что и было в начале
```

Остается только добавить проверку:

```
int n = 11111, r = 0, e = 1;
Console.Write(n + " => ");
while (n > 0)
{
    int d = n % 16;
    if (d % 2 == 0) r += d * e; // <== Добавили проверку
    e *= 16;
    n /= 16;
}
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: В вопросе же метка C++

Comment: @cppquestions, можете помощь — отредактируйте ответ, добавьте в него версию кода на плюсах :)